# Duplicate the value of a line to the following X lines in Sybase SQL

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have a problem with a query in Sybase SQL.
My query joins several tabbes.

However, I need help with this part.

My code is as follows:

```
trans_seq   dtl_seq     PLU_Uid     PLU_Name         Modifiers PLU_uid   Combo_uid
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- ----------------- -----------
17          1           3938          Menu 1           (NULL)            153 
17          2           3869          Product 1        (NULL)            (NULL) 
17          3           4148          Product 2        (NULL)            (NULL) 
17          4           4092          Product 3        (NULL)            (NULL)
17          5           3955          Product 4        (NULL)            (NULL)
17          6           3901          Product 5        (NULL)            (NULL)
17          7           3934          Menu 2           (NULL)            149
17          8           3865          Product 6        (NULL)            (NULL)
17          9           3960          Product 7        (NULL)            (NULL) 
17          10          4090          Product 3        (NULL)            (NULL)
17          11          3971          Product 8        (NULL)            (NULL)      
17          12          3917          Product 9        (NULL)            (NULL)
```

I would like the combo_uid to be repeated on the following 3 lines. Knowing this combo_uid, I will look for it on another table by making a join.

My desired code is:

```
trans_seq   dtl_seq     PLU_Uid     PLU_Name         Modifiers PLU_uid   Combo_uid
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- ----------------- -----------
17          1           3938          Menu 1           (NULL)            153 
17          2           3869          Product 1        (NULL)            153 
17          3           4148          Product 2        (NULL)            153 
17          4           4092          Product 3        (NULL)            153
17          5           3955          Product 4        (NULL)            (NULL)
17          6           3901          Product 5        (NULL)            (NULL)
17          7           3934          Menu 2           (NULL)            149
17          8           3865          Product 6        (NULL)            149
17          9           3960          Product 7        (NULL)            149 
17          10          4090          Product 3        (NULL)            149
17          11          3971          Product 8        (NULL)            (NULL)      
17          12          3917          Product 9        (NULL)            (NULL)
```

Do you have an idea or what function can help me do that?

Thanks for your help,
I look for several days

Comment: . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "following 3 lines", unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  No such column is obvious in your data.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your answer, I have 2 columns of which one is a sequence that corresponds to the number of lines in the transaction.

I edited the post in this sense

Comment: You still don't provide sufficient info as to why you would want 3 lines of one value for Combo_uid for some rows and yet the next should be null which you would need for the logic. Should there always be four lines for each matching id for example and if so whats the criteria for the match?
Ideally post all of your SQL with the joins as that will help most.